# Deserialize json array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, json, deserialization

I have a json array which is formatted as follows:

```
[
  {
    "property":96,
    "listofstuff":[
      {
        "anotherproperty":"some text here",
        "yetanother":"text goes here too"
      }
    ],
    "lastproperty":3001
  },
 <rest of array>
]
```

How can I deserialize this in such a way that I can have a list of objects indexed by `property`? Meaning, I want to be able to access the data like this: `MyList(96).lastproperty` or `MyList(96).listofstuff.yetanother` and have it return the proper datatype too? Is that even possible in vb.net?

Comment: I had actually tried parsing it with regex originally, which in hindsight does not seem like the smartest way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the JSON library you need to use is Json.NET found at http://json.codeplex.com/

So, given your example JSON array, I made the following classes that can be used for serializing and deserializing:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property [property]() As Integer
    Public Property listofstuff() As Stuff()
    Public Property lastproperty() As Integer
End Class

Public Class Stuff
    Public Property anotherproperty() As String
    Public Property yetanother() As String
End Class
```

Then all you need is the following code to be able to access the data in roughly the way you wanted to:

```
Dim Items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Item())(json)
Dim MyList = Items.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.property)
Dim Stuff = MyList(96).listofstuff(0)
```

If your intent with the `listofstuff` property array was to store any string pair then use this definition for `Item` (and you also won't need the `Stuff` class):

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property [property]() As Integer
    Public Property listofstuff() As Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    Public Property lastproperty() As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: `Items.ToDictionary` does not seem to exist?

Comment: Also if this code works as simply as it seems it will, then you've just saved me several hours of debugging ugly regexes.

Comment: Scratch that. I forgot a parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

You need a JSON library for .net: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: And how would i go about using that for this purpose?

Comment: from the author (see the LINQ to JSON example)  http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx Alternative if you want to strongly type you classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx