# Deserialize JSON array in VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

I have a web service that gives me a json with this format:

**In case of positive login:** ["67", 1];

**In the negative:** ["fail", "Data entered for the user is incorrect."]

How to properly deserialize?

I have tried :

```
Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim result = ser.Deserialize(Of LoginResult)(wsResult.ToString())

Public Class LoginResult
   Public Property idcliente As String
   Public Property idutente As String
End Class
```

Comment: For the C# part this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json array in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868863/deserialize-json-array-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use newtonsoft.JObject

```
   Dim json as jObject = JObject.Parse(yourJson)
    If (json.SelectToken("fail") = null)
      \\do somting
    If (json.SelectToken("67") = null)
      \\do somting
```