# Deserialize a JSON array (I know - not array) in VB.net using JSON.NET

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

I've been killing myself for days on this and I can't figure it out. I'm by no means a programmer and this is my first attempt at working with JSON.

I have a GUI that I'm writing in VB.NET which gathers information for a script. I am using JSON.NET. I have it capturing the data entered into the GUI and exporting it as a JSON file, but I now need the functionality of reading the JSON file and putting the data back into the GUI.

I'm reading the contents of the datafile like this:

```
Dim Json As String = File.ReadAllText(fileDlg.FileName)
Dim data As JObject = JObject.Parse(Json)
```

Then going through each element of the file pulling the data in like this:

```
AD_DomainNameTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.DomainName")
AD_FQDNTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.FQDN")
AD_DomainControllerTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.DomainController")
AD_SVCUsernameTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.SVCUsername")
AD_SVCPasswordTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.SVCPassword")
AD_BaseDNTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.BaseDN")
```

Now, I need to cycle through an array of Sites and Site details and enter those into a datagridview on the GUI. I know I can do a for next loop for each of the items, but I don't know how to identify the number of items in the array.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "ActiveDirectory": {
    "DomainName": "CORP",
    "FQDN": "corp.company.local",
    "DomainController": "DC01",
    "SVCUsername": "SVC_AD",
    "SVCPassword": "SuperPass1",
    "BaseDN": "OU=Active,DC=CORP,DC=Ccompany,DC=Local",
    "CreateOUs": true,
    "CreateGPOs": true,
    "Sites": [
      {
        "Site": "Prod",
        "HSA": "True",
        "HSD": "True",
        "HVD": null
      },
      {
        "Site": "Test",
        "HSA": "True",
        "HSD": null,
        "HVD": "True"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've looked at the documentation on the site pretty extensively, but I can't find what I'm looking for. I've tried reading it into a dataset, like https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm, and I've tried creating a Class like [Deserialize json array in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868863/deserialize-json-array-in-vb-net) but this doesn't make sense to me. It's way over my head.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please understand, that like I said, this is extremely new to me, so I need full details (don't assume that I know anything....because I don't!!)

Comment: What is the result of `data("ActiveDirectory")("Sites").Count`?

Comment: Deserializing is different than parsing.  The former doesnt require any sort of cycle (loop?).  Also, that JSOn doesnt look complete/valid.

Comment: @JacobKrall - I put in messagebox.show(data("ActiveDirectory").("Sites").Count) in the code and it returned: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @Plutonix - The JSON is not the complete text. It's just the piece I'm having the issue with. There is a block of data before with the specific customer's data and a block after with server locations. Would that help/be relevant to the question/answer? I can post more if necessary.

Comment: Incomplete JSON will not parse (nor deserialize) so there is little we can do to help other than guess *especially* if you want to Parse it

Comment: I didn't ask for `data("ActiveDirectory").("Sites").Count` -- I asked for `data("ActiveDirectory")("Sites").Count`. There shouldn't be a dot between the parentheses.

`data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.Sites").Count` will also work.

Comment: Ok. My mistake on the data("ActiveDirectory").("Sites").Count. Changing it to data("ActiveDirectory")("Sites").Count did return a correct 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Using [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm))*

The `ActiveDirectory.Sites` node is of type [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), which has a [`Count`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Count.htm) property.

You could iterate over the sites like this:

```
Dim Sites As JArray = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.Sites")
For I = 0 To Sites.Count - 1
    Dim Site = Sites(I)
    ' use `Site` and `I` in this loop body
Next
```

But if you don't care about the indexes, you should use a [`For Each`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) loop:

```
Dim Sites As JArray = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.Sites")
For Each Site In Sites
    ' use `Site` in this loop body
Next
```

[`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) also lets you access properties using the following [property lookup](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) syntax:

```
Dim ActiveDirectory = data("ActiveDirectory")
Dim Sites = ActiveDirectory("Sites")
Dim SiteCount = Sites.Count
```

So another way you could write it is:

```
For Each Site In data("ActiveDirectory")("Sites")
    ' use `Site` in this loop body
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Using your recommendations, I was able to get the desired data into the datagridview.
The code I used was probably longer than I needed it to be - as there's probably some built in functionality that I'm missing. I'll post what I did in case anyone finds it useful, or if there are recommendations on making more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendations, I've gotten the code to work as I needed.Posting the full block below:

```
        Dim Json As String = File.ReadAllText(fileDlg.FileName)
        Dim data As JObject = JObject.Parse(Json)
        Dim site
        Dim SiteName
        Dim HSA
        Dim HSD
        Dim HVD

        AD_DomainNameTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.DomainName")
        AD_FQDNTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.FQDN")
        AD_DomainControllerTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.DomainController")
        AD_SVCUsernameTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.SVCUsername")
        AD_SVCPasswordTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.SVBPassword")
        AD_BaseDNTB.Text = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.BaseDN")
        AD_CreateOUsCB.Checked = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.CreateOUs")
        AD_CreateGPOCB.Checked = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.CreateGPOs")

        Dim Sites As JArray = data.SelectToken("ActiveDirectory.Sites")
        For Each site In Sites
            SiteName = site.item("Site").ToString()
            HSA = site.item("HSA").ToString()
            HSD = site.item("HSD").ToString()
            HVD = site.item("HVD").ToString()

            If HSA = "" Then
                HSA = False
            End If
            If HSD = "" Then
                HSD = False
            End If
            If HVD = "" Then
                HVD = False
            End If
            AD_SitesDatagrid.Rows.Add({SiteName, HSA, HSD, HVD})
        Next
```

Now, there might be a better, more efficient way of going through the data in the array, but this worked.

Comment: You can use `site` directly instead of serializing and deserializing it again.

Comment: @JacobKrall - would you mind showing a modified snippet using site directly? I knew that there was probably a better way of getting the result, but I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: Cheers! Good luck with the rest of your project.