# Deserializing of collection with nested array in VB.NET and Newtonsoft

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, class, json.net

I want to convert a JSON string of quotes to a list of quotes, using Newtonsoft Deserializing of Collections.

I checked [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868863/deserialize-json-array-in-vb-net).

I get the error when I try to convert:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

I then tried changing the image property to:

```
Private _images As String()
Public Property images() As String()
    Get
        Return _images
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String())
        _images = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then I get error:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.String[].

How can I convert my JSON to my class so I have not only the author & quote string properties but also the image array as a strong type?

```
Public Class quote
    Private _author As String
    Public Property author() As String
        Get
            Return _author
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _author = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _quote As String
    Public Property quote() As String
        Get
            Return _quote
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _quote = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Dim quotesString As String = "[{""author"": ""J.K. Rowling"",""quote"": ""\u201cThe truth.\"" Dumbledore sighed. \""It is a beautiful and terrible thing, and should therefore be treated with great caution.\u201d"",""images"": [""dumbledore1.jpg"", ""dumbledore2.jpg"", ""dumbledore3.jpg""]}, {""author"": ""Jimi Hendrix"",""quote"": ""\u201cI'm the one that's got to die when it's time for me to die, so let me live my life the way I want to.\u201d"",""images"": [""Jimi.jpg"",""Jimi3.jpg"",""Jimi2.jpg""]},{""author"": ""J.M. Barrie"",""quote"": ""\u201cTo die will be an awfully big adventure.\u201d"",""images"": [""Barrie.jpg"",""Barrie1.jpg"",""Barrie2.jpg""]}]"

Dim quotes As List(Of quote) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of quote))(quotesString)
```

JSON SOURCE

```
[{
        "author": "J.K. Rowling",
        "quote": "\u201cThe truth.\" Dumbledore sighed. \"It is a beautiful and terrible thing, and should therefore be treated with great caution.\u201d",
        "images": ["dumbledore1.jpg", "dumbledore2.jpg", "dumbledore3.jpg"]
    }, {
        "author": "Jimi Hendrix",
        "quote": "\u201cI'm the one that's got to die when it's time for me to die, so let me live my life the way I want to.\u201d",
        "images": ["Jimi.jpg","Jimi3.jpg","Jimi2.jpg"]
    },
    {
        "author": "J.M. Barrie",
        "quote": "\u201cTo die will be an awfully big adventure.\u201d",
        "images": ["Barrie.jpg","Barrie1.jpg","Barrie2.jpg"]
    }

]
```

Comment: The content of your `images` property is not valid JSON, so you cannot deserialize it that way. You'll need to extract values using a regex (or `String.Split` in a pinch).

Comment: @Dai Thanks, I control the JSON source myself so I updated it now. Can you help?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using VB.NET?

Comment: Yes, working on a legacy project

Comment: You have my sympathy. What version of VB.NET are they forcing you to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change your property to `List<String>` (`List(Of String)` in VB.NET).

  - While `String[]` (`String()` in VB.NET) *should* work, I personally have fewer issues when deserializing JSON to `List<String>` - sometimes computers are spooky.
- You can also greatly simplify your VB.NET class definition to [use Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties): there's no need for explicit fields and boilerplate getter/setter logic.
- Also, in .NET: public members (properties, methods) should be `PascalCase`, as should type-names.

  - You can use the `JsonProperty` attribute to specify explicit JSON property names if they don't exactly match the .NET class member names (`Newtonsoft.Json` is case-sensitive by default).

    - Another approach is to configure `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` but I personally prefer explicit `[JsonProperty]` attributes.

```
Public Class Quote

    <JsonProperty("author")>
    Public Property Author As String

    <JsonProperty("quote")>
    Public Property Quote As String

    <JsonProperty("images")>
    Public Property Images As List(Of String)

End Class
```

Here's a screenshot of it running in Linqpad:

[image]